# Custom forms in Magento 2

Tags: php, forms, magento2

I am trying to create a custom form in Magento 2 and I can't send the form's action to the correct file.

So far I have the following module structure (I omitted some files for Models and CRUD which may not be necessary here, if  you need them I'll add them in the structure):

`- Block
   - Adminhtml
     * Main.php
 - Controller
   - Adminhtml
     - MySection
        * Settings.php
        * Save.php
 - etc
   - adminhtml
     * menu.xml
     * routes.xml
   * acl.xml
   * module.xml
 - Setup
   * InstallSchema.php
 - view
   - adminhtml
     - layout
       * modulename_mysection_settings.xml
       * modulename_mysection_save.xml
     - templates
       * mysectionContent.phtml
       * content.phtml
 * registration`

etc\adminhtml\routes.xml contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="modulename" frontName="modulename">
            <module name="modulename"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

view\adminhtml\layout\modulename_mysection_settings.xml contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>My Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="content">
            <block template="mysectionContent.phtml"
                    class="Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Main"
                    name="modulenameadminbackend_block_main"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

view\adminhtml\templates\mysectionContent.phtml

```
<h1>My H1 Title</h1>

<form class="form" action="save" method="post">

    <fieldset class="fieldset">
        <legend class="legend"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Test Form') ?></span></legend><br>
        <div class="field required">
            <label for="number" class="label">
                <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Input') ?></span>
            </label>

            <div class="control">
                <input type="text" id="number" name="number" class="input-text">
                <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getFormKey() ?>" />

            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <div class="primary">
            <button type="submit" class="action submit primary" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Submit') ?>">
                <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Submit') ?></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

Is there a way that I can instruct the form that its action will be file Controller/Adminhtml/MySection/Save.php ? If a Controller's file is not the correct place for a form to be submitted, then please tell me where it should be and how do I do this. Afterwards I need to retrieve the submitted post variables from that file. 
I am new in Magento and I can't seem to be able to find any tutorial about submitting forms

Comment: Should I move this question to [Magento Stack Exchange](https://magento.stackexchange.com)?

Answer (score 0):

make the `action` attribute on the form like this

```
action="<?php echo $block->getUrl('modulename/mySection/save')?>"
```

On a side note. You should not create admin forms using blocks and templates. 
Use [ui-components](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/ui_comp_guide/components/components-intro.html). you can take as example the cms module and do the same.